# Do we need/have a tag for management issues?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a few good questions about getting Management/ect to fund/play nice with UX and usability research, such as ["Selling" the management on need for UX focus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18862/selling-the-management-on-need-for-ux-focus) and [How to sell people on the benefits of user research?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20342/how-do-sell-people-on-the-benefits-of-user-research#question)

Do we have a tag to apply to these questions about management rather than the actual design process? If not, what should the tag be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need a special tag for these selling questions, and I couldn't find any useful existing tag. We could use general terms such as [convince](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convince) or [persuade](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persuade). The problem with those is that they would probably<sup>*guessing*</sup> not be found or used, and require moderation from the community.

Maybe a [selling](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selling) or [selling-ux](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selling-ux) tag could do the trick, especially since both questions use **selling** as part of the title.

---

## Edit

The tag [selling-ux](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selling-ux) is now implemented.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking something like selling. Seems a bit specific...but also fits the questions we have

Comment: @BenBrocka I just implemented it - and have tagged four questions (including my own) :-)  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selling-ux

Comment: Works for me. There's probably more too